# Tomcat failing to deploy my servlet on Tomcat within Eclipse (NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: eclipse, apache, maven, tomcat7, m2eclipse

I have a Hello Wolrd Servlet in a Maven project created with Java EE Eclipse (Juno). The pom.xml specifies the following dependancies:

- junit
- tomcat-servlet-api

"Run As > Maven install" seems to run fine and outputs a .war file in /target/.

This .war deploys (Apache app manager) and runs fine on an other machine using tomcat 7.0.26-1ubuntu1.2 (installed via apt-get).

I configured Eclipse (using the server view) to use an apache-tomcat-7.0.40 install that I extracted from a tar.gz archive. It also runs fine using "Run As > Run on Server".

Now, if I add this to the Hello World servlet:

```
PropertiesConfiguration config = new
PropertiesConfiguration("config.properties");
```

and

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;
```

and add the following dependency to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

It keeps running fine on the distant server, but when using "Run As > Run on Server" in Eclipse, it fails, which is not cool for efficient dev & debug:

```
May 30, 2013 6:42:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
May 30, 2013 6:42:28 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:proxy' did not find a matching property.
May 30, 2013 6:42:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 30, 2013 6:42:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-5443"]
May 30, 2013 6:42:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 30, 2013 6:42:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 561 ms
May 30, 2013 6:42:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 30, 2013 6:42:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.40
May 30, 2013 6:42:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/proxy]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/proxy]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/ConfigurationException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2318)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1762)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5269)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 21 more
May 30, 2013 6:42:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
May 30, 2013 6:42:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
May 30, 2013 6:42:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 239 ms
```

Reading a bunch of posts, I found a way to make it work doing "Properties > Deployment Assembly > Add > Java Build Path Entries > Maven Dependencies", but Maven resets this setting on a "Maven > Update Project".

Is it possible to define an appropriate setting within the pom.xml to avoid this issue ?

Extra info: I'm using maven-compiler-plugin and maven-war-plugin. (may be the wrong way!)

Comment: (Probably) unrelated, but you must not deploy your own servlet-api; do you have it defined as "provided" in your pom?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I updated to "provided", it still runs fine on the distant server and fails on the eclipse integrated one.

I just did a diff of the project between after and before the "Properties > Deployment Assembly > Add > Java Build Path Entries > Maven Dependencies" and here is the result:

/project/.classpath is different:
`<    <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>`


So I think eclipse doesn't make use of the .war, or at least not only, and makes use of this .classpath file. Any idea how to make maven generate this file correctly ?

Comment: I followed:

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/eclipse-web-deployment-assembly-maven-dependencies-issue/

`mvn clean` then `mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0` then `mvn install` then "Run as..."

`/project/org.eclipse.wst.common.component` was created and contains:

`<dependent-module archiveName="commons-logging-1.1.1.jar" deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/classpath/var/M2_REPO/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar">`

Now, either I have errors at deploy time, either localhost/project/servlet leads to an Err404...

2nd method did not improve things either.

Answer (score 0):

Use m2e-wtp to integrate seamlessly with wtp : https://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/

Comment: I added the plugin but I did not notice any change.

However, I found a solution:

Create a maven project using the `maven-archetype-webapp` archetype instead of creating an eclipse dynamic web project and using `configure > Convert to maven project`.

After some changes, it failed again either on the same `NoClassDefFoundError` either on `Err 404: Ressource not found` .

Using a fresh server declaration in the Eclipse server view (with the same tomcat install) fixed the issue.

A diff on the "Servers" project configuration files did not reveal any relevant difference.

Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: BTW, given your profile, you may have interests in knowing my dev environment (after installing m2e-wtp) :

`Name/Version`

`Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.5.2.20130211-1820`
`m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.3.1.20130219-1424`
`m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.3.1.20130219-1424`
`m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP (Incubation) 0.17.0.20130212-1821`
`Subversive SVN Connectors 3.0.0.I20130122-1700`
`Subversive SVN Team Provider 1.0.0.I20130122-1700`
`SVNKit 1.3.8 Implementation (Optional) 3.0.0.I20121228-1700`
`Terminal 1.1.2.201208131620`

Comment: Doing Maven > Update Project after installing m2e-wtp should work.

Comment: Mat be it should, but as stated in my original post, it did not. Anyway, now it's fixed

Comment: If you manage to reproduce the problem, then please open a bug report with a sample test project at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=M2E-WTP

Comment: Yep, I'll try to find some time for this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably,
You need to set the maven dependencies as a part of deployment assembly.

Eclipse -> Project->properties->Deployment Assembly ->Add -> Java Build path entries-> Choose maven dependencies.

This will make your pom dependencies to get bundle as a part of your web archive ( web-inf/lib).

Comment: Right, but as I stated in my question (which may be too long :P), this setting gets reseted everytime you run a maven build or `Maven > Update project`..